# Phonegap android app using durandal : page with ajax call not opening

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, durandal

I'm fairly new with android I got an issue that page with ajax call is not loading in native app developed using Phonegap.

Cross-domain `AJAX POST`-request works perfectly fine on web browsers including browsers on mobile phones, but doesn't work for native applications built using Phonegap.

I have created an app in `durandal` that gets data from `Facebook` and shows in a page. It works fine in the browsers but the page with ajax call is not loaded in the native app built using `Phonegap`. Note: other static pages works fine.

**My Ajax script:**

```
define(function(require){
  return {
    getCustomers:function(){
      //do some ajax and return a promise
        return $.ajax({
          url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?',
          dataType: 'json',
        }).promise();
    }
  };
});
```

**Domain whitelisting - config.xml**

```
<access origin="*"/>
<!-- <content src="http://mysite.com/myapp.html" /> for external pages -->
<content src="index.html" />
```

**User permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I got an error. I don't know is that relevant to this?

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'parentElement' [null] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:41
```

Answer (score 1):

CORS parameter must be enabled in your server end as well, along with passing the "mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;" in phonegap.

search for CORS related quetions in stackoverflow, there are many solutions.

Let me explain why it works in mobile browser but not on phonegap packaging. Phonegap packaging pulls the files from the application's local file system, making the reference domain as "Local". When you make a request to the URL, it is apparently in a different domain, hence the CORS. Enabling CORS parameter in phonegap configuration mostly solves the issue. In  case it pertains, you must check that the webservice/URL supports the CORS. Look for server side CORS parameter enabling.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Anyway, Try adding this to the head code,

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});
```

and also try removing the `,` here

```
    return $.ajax({
      url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?',
      dataType: 'json' //<<---HERE
    }).promise();
```

is it `json` or `jsonp` ?

Comment: I think facebook is returning 'json'. It working fine in browser